# Python - Calculate Sum of All Pairs

Tags: python, sum

I had a test question recently that asked to take a list and calculate all pair sums from a given list and then return the number of times the sum was equal to a given target value.

I wrote the code, and thought it was right at the time, but it looks like it counts pairs twice. I would like to figure out a way to ensure I don't double count the pairs.

I obviously didn't get the interview question correctly. My thought would be to store which indices have already been summed and skip them if they have?

*Pairs DO NOT have to be consecutive

```
myList = [1,4,6,7,8]

def getSums(myList,target):
    l_ = len(myList)
    sums = []
    for i in range(l_):
        for j in range(l_):
            if i==j:
                continue
            else:
                sums.append((myList[i],myList[j],myList[i]+myList[j]))
    return [x for x in sums if x[2]==target]

print getSums(myList,5)
```

Comment: You said it should sum a list of pairs, but you're using a list of plain numbers. Do you mean get the sum of each consecutive number? Also, what's your specific question? Having people may generally look over code for you isn't appropriate here.

Comment: Apologies, the pairs do not have to be consecutive. I will adjust the original question

Comment: Are you allowed to use `itertools.combinations`? eg: `total = sum(sum(el) == 5 for el in combinations(mylist, 2))` ?

Comment: Although, if you've got an ordered list of only positive integers, an easy win is to use `bisect` on it to cut out pairs that could never meet the total required...

Comment: @JonClements: There's an easier and faster solution with a `set`.

Comment: Are `(1, 4)` and `(4, 1)` considered distinct pairs?

Comment: @pylang Yes, if they are from distinct indices. The real question I believe he was getting at was to computer sums of index pairs that equal a target

Comment: What do you mean by "index pairs"?

Comment: if (1,4) and (4,1) came from different index pairs, then they should be treated separately. if they came from the same indices, don't double count them

Comment: Ok.  So `(myList[0], myList[1])` and `(myList[1], myList[0])` and not distinct?

Comment: @pylang yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like that:

```
from collections import Counter
myList = [1,4,6,7,8]

c = Counter(myList)

sum([k for k,v in c.items() if v == 2])
```

modified first example ( not tested, just logic example ):

```
myList = [1,4,6,7,8]

def getSums(myList,target):
    l_ = len(myList)
    sums = []
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        for item in myList[i:]:
            sums.append((myList[i],item,myList[i]+item))
    return [x for x in sums if x[2]==target]

print getSums(myList,5)
```

Comment: I think this is one way to do it, but the point of the test question would be to do it with as little libraries as possible

Comment: @chattrat423 well, if so, you could iterate over list directly in second loop just slicing list by `i`

Comment: @chattrat423 I'd rather see you use tools the language provides rather than re-write (and potentially incorrectly) your own :)

Comment: @JonClements true in practice I would, but the point of a computer science course is to actually know how to code it yourself

Comment: Ahh.. but if you write it in a way that'd you do so in real life - you've got something that gives you correct results, then you can start writing your own and comparing it as you go along... (even look at the way the standard library has done it if you get stuck/want inspiration)

Comment: What is the first method doing? It doesn't seem to fit OP's problem. It just checks if an element appears twice.

Comment: @EricDuminil it sums all elements repieted twice or i misunderstood op's requirements

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov: I don't think it's the desired result. The other method seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here we emulate a watered-down version of `itertools.combinations`.

**Code**

```
def combinations(iterable):
    """Return r=2 combinations of an iterable."""
    # Inherently, r=2 (pairs) by using two loops
    pool = []
    for idx_i, i in enumerate(iterable):
        for idx_j, j in enumerate(iterable):
            if (idx_i != idx_j) and ((j,i) not in pool):
                pool.append((i, j))
    return pool


def get_sums(iterable, target):
    """Return the tally of summed paired equal to the target value."""
    results = [sum(i) for i in combinations(lst)]
    return len([i for i in results if i == 5])


get_sums([1, 4, 6, 7, 8], 5)
# 1
```

**Details**

Let's split the problem into 3 steps:

1. make combinations of pairs (with certain restrictions)

   - assuming no repeated indices, i.e. `idx_i != idx_j`
   - assuming `(lst[0], lst[1])` is not distinct from `(lst[1], lst[0])`
2. filter pairs whose sum equal the target
3. count the filtered result

**Options**

`itertools` is certainly nicer if allowed:

```
import itertools as it

lst, target = [1, 4, 6, 7, 8], 5
results = [sum(i) for i in list(it.combinations(lst, 2))]
len([i for i in results if i == target])
# 1
```

In fact, I started with the `itertools` solution and worked backwards, clearing out the basic logic and later substituting the module dependency.  Perhaps this is a strategy that can be used for "reinvent the wheel" scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have to calculate the sum of all the pairs? It's very inefficient and not required. With a set, you can solve this problem in one single pass and no external library.

The algorithm works this way :

- create an empty set
- create an empty list
- iterate over every element of the input list:

  - check if `target - element` has already been seen.

    - If yes, a new pair has been found : add it to the list
  - mark `element` as already seen.

Here's the code:

```
myList = [1,4,6,0,2,7,8,3,5]

def getSums(myList,target):
    already_seen = set()
    pairs = []
    for x in myList:
        if (target - x) in already_seen:
            pairs.append((x, target - x))
        already_seen.add(x)
    return pairs

print(getSums(myList,5))
# [(4, 1), (3, 2), (5, 0)]
```

This solution should work with any list with unique elements. The list doesn't need to be sorted. Complexity is `O(n)`, compared to `O(n**2)` for the other solutions.

If elements aren't unique, you can use a `Counter` instead of a `set`:

```
myList = [1,4,6,0,2,7,8,3,5]

from collections import Counter
def getSums(myList,target):
    already_seen = Counter()
    pairs = []
    for x in myList:
        for _ in range(already_seen[target - x]):
            pairs.append((x, target - x))
        already_seen[x] += 1
    return pairs

print(getSums(myList,5))
# [(4, 1), (3, 2), (5, 0)]
print(getSums([2, 2, 2],4))
# [(2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)]
```

The last result is consistent with the other answers.

Comment: I don't think using set would allow us to retain the true number of times any pairs summed to the target, we would lose the total count

Comment: @chattrat423: Do you have any other example? It works fine if the list has unique elements. If not, a simple Counter would do.

Comment: All depends if the number of pairs equalling 4 for [2, 2, 2] should be 1, 2 or 3 (maybe even none)... on what an approach can be...

Comment: @chattrat423: See the update. Nothing is lost and it seems to work fine with repeated elements.

Comment: @JonClements: See the update. If repeated elements are allowed, I'd say that 3 is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I think it double-counts because you are going through the list twice, once through index i, and once through index j.

I got the following code to produce the correct result.  I added the value 3 so that I could see if it would spot all pairs that sum to 10.

```
myList = [1,3,4,6,7,8]
target = 10

def getSums(myList,target):
    l_ = len(myList)
    sums = []
    for i in range(l_):
        for j in range(l_):
            if i!=j:
                if (myList[i] + myList[j]) == target:
                    if myList[i] not in sums:
                        sums.append(myList[i])
                        sums.append(myList[j])
    print sums



getSums(myList, target)
```